# How to get all JSON data inside the brackets using fetch?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I am newbie to react native and I would like to create a simple app to fetch JSON data.

Here is my json file.

```json
[
  {
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
  },
  {
    "fruit": "Orange",
    "size": "big",
    "color": "Orange"
  }
]
```

Here is my react native code

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: '' };
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch('https://othersite.my.json', {
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    data: responseJson
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>
                    {this.state.data}
                    //for debug {this.state.data.fruit}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you set correct path to the my.json.it might be similar to the ./my.json or ./../my.json

Comment: sorry about my unclear description,it is not my own json file in my host, it using another site HTTPS URL path ,Thx

Comment: What have you got in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fetch looks good in there. Considering you are able to fetch data from the API and set the state. You can use map() function to display your data

```
render(){
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       {this.state.data.map((item) => {
         console.log(item.fruit)
         console.log(item.size)
         console.log(item.color)
       })
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It work fine :) . have a nice day

Comment: and change this.state = { data: '' }; to  this.state = { data: [] };

Answer (score 0):

If the json file is inside your react project, you can import the like this:

```
const fruits = require('path/to/json/my.json');
console.log(fruits[0].size);
```